# Generic backend system

Tags: open-source, framework, admin-console

We are writing several SaaS products and we are looking for a free-software generic backend system that can be connected to our products and can be configured or extended to accomplish the following actions:

1. Transition users of the administrated application through application workflow (e.g. confirmation pending -> confirmed in the sign-up scenario).
2. Display a dashboard with application KPIs.  Allow to download a report with the KPIs.
3. Display a monitoring dashboard with systems KPIs.

The system should also have a notion of users, roles, resources, privileges, and privilege policies, and implement the logic of resource access privileges. (À la [AWS IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam) yet that level of detail would be a bit over the top.)

The ideal case for an interesting answer would be to find a software that allows me to realise 1, 2 and 3 by implementing a class describing the details of the operation and the connection to our software products.

On the other side of the interest spectrum, a library implementing resource access privileges logic would still be interesting.

Software written in Java, Python, PHP would be a good match, but answers mentioning tools in other languages are welcome.